# How can I serve unbuffered CGI content from Apache 2?

Tags: python, perl, apache2, cgi

I would like to be able to allow a user to view the output of a long-running GCI script as it is generated rather than after the script is complete.   However even when I explicitly flush STDOUT the server seems to wait for the script to complete before sending the response to the client. This is on a Linux server running Apache 2.2.9.

Example python CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import sys


print "Content-type: text/plain"
print
for i in range(1, 10):
        print i
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

print "Done."
```

Similar example in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10 ; $i++) {
        print "$i\n";
        sleep(1);
}

print "Done.";
```

This link says as of Apache 1.3 CGI output should be unbuffered (but this might apply only to Apache 1.x): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ-F.html#nph-scripts

Any ideas?

Comment: You may also potentially be running into client (browser)-side buffering issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randal Schwartz's article [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html) explains a different (and IMHO, better) way of watching a long running process.

Comment: I ended up using a similar method for my application but I'm still curious as to why the original method isn't working in my setup. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Flushing STDOUT can help. For example, the following Perl program should work as intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $| = 1;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ ) {
    print "$i\n";
    sleep(1);
}

print "Done.";
```

Answer (score 2):

You must put your push script into a special directory wich contain a special .htaccess
with this environnment specs:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .sh .pl .py
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type \
"^multipart/form-data;" "MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads"
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

Comment: How is this related to file uploads?

Answer (score 1):

According to [CGI::Push](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI/Push.pm),

> Apache web server from version 1.3b2
>   on does not need server push scripts
>   installed as NPH scripts: the -nph
>   parameter to do_push() may be set to a
>   false value to disable the extra
>   headers needed by an NPH script.

You just have to find do_push equivalent in python.

**Edit**: Take a look at [CherryPy: Streaming the response body](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ReturnVsYield).

> When you set the config entry "response.stream" to True (and use "yield") CherryPy manages the conversation between the HTTP server and your code like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cherrypy.org](http://www.cherrypy.org/attachment/wiki/ReturnVsYield/cpyield.gif?format=raw))</sub>