# Displaying Console Ouput in Browser while the Perl Script is still running

Tags: php, perl

Here's very simple program that I am testing on

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "This is Test Script\n";
sleep(5);

print "This is Test Script\n";
sleep(5);

print "This is Test Script\n";
sleep(5);

print "This is Test Script\n";
sleep(5);

print "This is Test Script\n";
sleep(5);

print "Script Testing Done\n";
```

Now PHP should output the script output (which is going to console) every maybe 10 seconds or 5 seconds or whenever the php sees the output on the console.

I have hundreds of perl scripts and I cannot go and change those script and direct the output to a file where php/ajax can get the content and output to the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, what? You're having PHP call Perl scripts?

Comment: Very similar question (with good answers) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181135/how-can-i-serve-unbuffered-cgi-content-from-apache-2

Comment: Yes, I am Calling Perl script from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) and [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush).

The former allows you to read/write to processes at will. The latter flushes the output buffer.

(Edit, add example code)

Here is a sample PHP script that invokes your Perl sample above (assuming its called `test.pl`). Note that due to Perl's output buffering mechanism, you need to tell your Perl script to make STDOUT implicitly flush (or "make it hot" in Perl-speak). You can do this by adding `$|=1` at the top of your Perl script.

```
<?php

$descriptor = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin
   1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout
   2 => array("pipe", "w"), // stderr
);

$proc = proc_open('./test.pl', $descriptor, $pipes);
if ($proc) {
    fclose($pipes[0]); // no input
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0); // turn off blocking
    while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
        echo "PHP> (heartbeat)\n";
        $fromPerl = fread($pipes[1], 1024); // read up to 1k
        if ($fromPerl) {
            echo "Perl> {$fromPerl}";
        }
        sleep(2); // do other work instead
    }
    proc_close($proc);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ time php proc.php 
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> This is Test Script
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> This is Test Script
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> This is Test Script
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> This is Test Script
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> This is Test Script
PHP> (heartbeat)
PHP> (heartbeat)
Perl> Script Testing Done
PHP> (heartbeat)

real    0m30.031s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.018s
```

Comment: Hi Scoates, Can you just provide some code how can I use these two functions?

Comment: I added an example script and its output.

Comment: Thanks A lot Scoates...That example is Awesome.. I really Appreciate it.

Comment: You should accept it if it answers your question (-: If not, what part is still unclear?

Comment: +1 @scoates: but is there any why to return SUCCESS/FAILURE flag and stop the perl process sth like that , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I might be barking up the wrong tree here, but isn't it possible that you are [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Um, back in the old days I'd use CGI with non-parsed headers (NPH... google it) and `$|=1` "when you want your pipes to be piping hot".

You're going to have to do something similar with the PHP side.