# Reg: Perl CGI script Autoupdate with New Data

Tags: perl

Hi This script is taking 3*2 secs time and then printing the output in the browser at once, help re

```
#!C:/perl/bin/perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header();
print $cgi->start_html("First");
print $cgi->h1("First");
sleep(2);
print $cgi->h1("Second");
sleep(2);
print $cgi->h1("Third");
print $cgi->end_html();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I serve unbuffered CGI content from Apache 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181135/how-can-i-serve-unbuffered-cgi-content-from-apache-2)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600495/how-to-write-a-perl-cgi-script-which-keeps-on-flushing-with-current-time-in-the by the same OP.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `$| = 1;` to flush the output buffer with each print, but it looks like [Apache will wait for the script to finish running](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=150578) before returning anything, so you might need to move your sleep logic into client side JavaScript.