# load web page incrementally?

Tags: php, perl

I am running a perl cgi script on a server which processes given text to be downloaded to user's browser.  In some cases the text can be quite long, and the user could be waiting quite some time to see anything before the script is finished running.  Even though I am sending a print command for each block of text that is processed, still no text appears until the script is finally finished.

Is there a way to allow the user to see each block of text as it is processed, without having to wait until the entire page is finished?

I have spent a little time looking into lazy loaders for images which use jquery, but offhand they don't appear to be the solution I am looking for.

I could also use PHP to serve the page if need be.

Thanks, Allasso

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reg: Perl CGI script Autoupdate with New Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597184/reg-perl-cgi-script-autoupdate-with-new-data)

Answer (score 0):

"EventSource" and "Server-side events" are appropriate keywords to search.  2 very helpful links:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp (i can't help it, it works and it's simple...)
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

-EDIT - another very good resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

For a quick-start, I used the example from w3schools:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
  {
  var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_sse.php:
(EDIT - changed demo_sse.php to a more relevant example)

```
<?php

  header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

  while (1) {
    $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
  }

?>
```